# pointers in c (beginner)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I just started to look at C, coming from a java background. I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around pointers. In theory I feel like I get it but as soon as I try to use them or follow a program that's using them I get lost pretty quickly. I was trying to follow a string concat exercise but it wasnt working so I stripped it down to some basic pointer practice. It complies with a warning conflicting types for strcat function and when I run it, crashes completly.

Thanks for any help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* strcat: concatenate t to end of s; s must be big enough */
void strcat(char *string, char *attach);


int main(){
char one[10]="test";
char two[10]="co";
char *s;
char *t;
s=one;
t=two;
strcat(s,t);
}

void strcat(char *s, char *t) {

    printf("%s",*s);




}
```

Comment: Print s, not *s..

Comment: aha that works thanks! I thought I had to use *s to access the value, instead I just use s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `printf()` should look like this:

```
printf("%s",s);
```

The asterisk is unnecessary. The `%s` format argument means that the argument should be a `char*`, which is what `s` is.  Prefixing `s` with `*` does an extra invalid indirection.

You get the warning about conflicting types because `strchr` is a standard library routine, which should have this signature:

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

Yours has a different return type.  You should probably rename yours to `mystrchr` or something else to avoid the conflict with the standard library (you may get linker errors if you use the same name).

Comment: Thanks for the explination :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
printf("%s",*s);
```

to

```
printf("%s",s);
```

The reason for this is printf is expecting a replacement for `%s` to be a pointer.  It will dereference it internally to get the value.

Since you declared `s` as a `char` pointer (`char *s`), the type of `s` in your function will be just that, a pointer to a `char`.  So you can just pass that pointer directly into `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, when you dereference a pointer, you get the value pointed to by the pointer. In this case, you get the first character pointed to by s. The correct usage should be:

```
printf( "%s", s );
```

BTW, strcat is a standard function that returns a pointer to a character array. Why make your own?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `*s` with `s` won't append strings yet, here is fully working code :

---

Pay attention to function `urstrcat`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* urstrcat: concatenate t to end of s; s must be big enough */
void urstrcat(char *string, char *attach);


int main(){
char one[10]="test";
char two[10]="co";
char *s;
char *t;
s=one;
t=two;
urstrcat(s,t);
return 0;
}

void urstrcat(char *s, char *t) {

    printf("%s%s",s,t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pointers are variable which points to address of a variable.

```
#include "stdio.h"
void main(){
  int a,*b;
  a=10;
  b=&a;
  printf("%d",b);
}
```

in the follwing code you will see a int 'a' and a pointer 'b'.
here b is taken as pointer of an integer and declared by giving
'*' before it.'*' declare that 'b' is an pointer.then you will see "b=&a".this means b is taking address of integer "a" which is keeping value 10 in that particular memory and printf is printing that value.